# How to indicate position to the center of the parent in java code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am confused on the following:
If I have a LinearLayout as part of a hierarchy and I want to programmatically change its position so that it is in the center of the parent layout how can I do this?
There are too many gravity attributes.
Should I update the gravity of the layout params of the item or of the parent?

Comment: What is its parent? Different ViewGroups have different LayoutParams...

Comment: @FletcherJohns:So isn't `gravity` always the one to set?

Comment: Gravity controls the position of a View's contents, not the position of the View within its parent.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent is a LinearLayout you can use `android:layout_gravity="center"` on that view to center it in its parents view.

If the parent is a RelativeLayout you can use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

I would generally use a RelativeLayout as a parent view if you want to center views inside it

Comment: Also, read this for more info https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/